# VS 2015 database with sql authentication

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

Up to now I always had access to a real server on which I had SQL server available to connect to. That was not a problem.

Now I want to add a database locally on my laptop but with SQL authentication.
I can add a database and I have added a user to the logins. But how do I map this user to the database?
In SQL server 2010+ I had a window that made that easy.
But I cannot find that in Visual Studio/SQL server.

Comment: You can install Sql Server Management Studio, connect to localdb instance installed by VisualStudio and use it for any database management as usual.

Comment: that is so simple I feel stupid now...

Comment: There is **no** SQL Server **2010** version - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016 and 2017 - take your pick .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Andy Komeyev stated: install SSMS.